# Чи є правильним слово "сякальник"?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів

Читаючи роман *[Стівена Кінга "Воно"](https://coollib.net/b/387662/read)* зустріла дивне для мене слово ***"сякальник"***. *"Він дістав з кишені сякальника, щоб витерти ніс"*.

Лише з самого контексту речення було зрозуміло, що мова йдеться про ***[носовичок (носова хустка)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%85%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)***. В українській мові є слово "[сякатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/sjakatysja)", але чи є правильним слово ***"сякальник"***? Чи можна вживати це слово? Чи можливо це все неточності перекладу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ЕСУМі можна знайти слово "[сяка](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf)" (ст. 496), тобто шмарклі. Однак, слова "сякальник" ні там, ні де-інде мені знайти не вдалося.

Хоч враховуючи те, що є слово "сяка", а ще "сякало", "сякач" та "висякатися" я можу припустити, що в якомусь діалекті існує слово "сякальник", тобто носовий платок. На [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) про перифраз є такі слова: *"..."обійтися допомогою носової хустки" замість "висякатися"..."* (тут йдеться про ефимізми), тому гадаю, що таке слово як "сякальник" не варто вживати занадто часто, бо якщо "висякатися" відноситься до "низьких" понять, то гадаю, що і туди ж може відноситися слово "сякальник" (однак врахуйте, що це інформація із Вікіпедії, тому не можна довіряти їй на 100%).

Проте, я гадаю, що це слово і справді звучить досить грубо, а якщо ще й врахувати те, що його немає в жодному офіційному джерелі, думаю, що краще вживати слова "[носовик](http://sum.in.ua/s/nosovyk)" або "[носова хустинка](http://sum.in.ua/s/khustynka)".

Answer (score 3):

У словниках (наприклад, [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), словники на [R2U](http://r2u.org.ua/), словники на [E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/)) немає. Здається, діалектизм або авторський неологізм.

Цікаво, що іноді вживають у значенні «ніс»:

> *От за то й вигребли прямісінько в красномовнокрючкуватий сякальник* (з форуму¹).

<sup>(¹ Для бажаючих наведу посилання на конкретне повідомлення форуму, але я попереджую — контент дуже неприємний: [посилання](http://forum.meta.ua/viewtopic.php?t=206831#post_9965921).)</sup>

Comment: Коли так, непоганиь неолӧґізм, за словотвором підходить.